# Не ловится клик по элементу с определенным класcом JS

Tags: javascript, html

Хочу словить клик , но выдает такую ошибку
"TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null"

```js
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementByClassName('card').onclick = function(){
  alert('click');}
}
```

```html
 <button alt="" class="card" id="T-Shirt" >
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName, s забыл. И да, эта функция вернет массив, поэтому надо будет обращаться к его первому элементу

Comment: Тоесть вот так getElementsByClassName('card')[0].onclick  ?

Comment: ++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: А с ошибкой что делать? Она все еще осталась

Comment: что выводит console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('card'))
?

Comment: Да, естественно, document.getElementsByClassName('card'), а не getElementsByClassName('card')